# Can't get any response from Nodejs API on remote server

Tags: node.js, express, remote-server

i have a Nodejs API using express and mongoose, when i test the api locally i get the desired response, but when i deployed the API i execute the command node server.js, which outputs connected to mongo database, but i can't get response to any request

server.js file :

```
const http= require('http');
const port=3000;
const app=require('./app')
const server=http.createServer(app);





server.listen(3000,"0.0.0.0");
```

app.js file :

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

const userRoutes=require('./routes/users');
const associatesRoutes=require('./routes/associates');

const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const mongoose=require('mongoose')




app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*')
    if(req.method==='Options'){
        res.header('Access-Control-ALlow-Methods','PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE')
        res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
const url = 'mongodb://*****';
mongoose.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to database")
})


app.use('/users',userRoutes);

app.use('/associates',associatesRoutes);


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    const error=new Error('Not found');
    error.status=404;
    next(error)
})

app.use((error, req, res, next)=> {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    });
})

module.exports=app;
```

i get a response that the user is created when i send the request locally, but nothing when i try on the remote server, i verified if the 3000 port is available and i also checked for firewall and found it inactive, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: _Deployed_ where and how?

Comment: i pushed the code to a git repo and cloned the repository to the remote server using ssh access

Answer (score 0):

Is Mongo up & running?

can you confirm that you are seeing this log "`Connected to database`"?

How do you run your app on the server? do you use `'node fileName.js'` to run it?

Comment: i do see the log Connected to database when i launch the commande node server.js, so yea i guess the database is up and running, but no response from requests

Comment: can you get a response on the server using 127.0.0.1 instead of the server ip? I mean locally on the server do you get a response? instead of using node command try using pm2